# how do i pass data from a jsp full of jquery to java class

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I'm writing a todo list portlet in liferay, i got the visual part done using some jsp pages filled with javascript, html and css and now I have to write the business logic. First thing i have to do is to pass some object from jquery to java class so i can write a connector for liferay and then make the persistence model. Can anyone help with this? Here is the code:

```
Query.noConflict();

 function Todo (pMainFoldersDivId) {
  this.mainFoldersDivId = pMainFoldersDivId;
  this.folders = new Array();
  this.addFolderPopup;
  this.editFolderPopup;
  this.manageFoldersPopup;
  this.quickNotesPopup;

  this.addQuickNote = function() {
    this.quickNotesPopup = new QuickNotesPopup();
    this.quickNotesPopup.show();
}

this.saveQuickNote1 = function() {
    var qnote1 = jQuery('#quicknote1 textarea').val();
}
this.saveQuickNote2 = function() {
    var qnote2 = jQuery('#quicknote2 textarea').val();
}
this.saveQuickNote3 = function() {
    var qnote3 = jQuery('#quicknote3 textarea').val();
}

this.addNote = function() {
    alert('addNote');
}

this.addFolder = function() {
    if(typeof this.manageFoldersPopup != 'undefined') {
        this.manageFoldersPopup.hide();
    }

    this.addFolderPopup = new AddFolderPopup();
    this.addFolderPopup.show();
}   

this.createFolder = function() {
    var folderTitle = jQuery('#input-folder-title').val();
    var folderIcon = jQuery('#select-folder-icon').val();
    var folderBgImage = jQuery('#select-folder-bgimage').val();

    var folder = new TwFolder('10', folderIcon, folderTitle, folderBgImage);
    this.folders.push(folder);

    this.addFolderPopup.hide();
    this.renderFolders();
}

this.updateFolder = function() {
    var folderId = jQuery('#input-folder-id').val();
    var folderTitle = jQuery('#input-folder-title').val();
    var folderIcon = jQuery('#select-folder-icon').val();
    var folderBgImage = jQuery('#select-folder-bgimage').val();

    var arrFolder = jQuery.grep(this.folders, function(folder,idx) {
        return folder.id == folderId;
    });
    if(arrFolder.length > 0) {
        var folder = arrFolder[0];
        folder.title = folderTitle;
        folder.icon = folderIcon;
        folder.bgImage = folderBgImage;

        this.renderFolders();
        this.editFolderPopup.hide();
        this.manageFolders();
    }
}

this.editFolder = function(pFolderId) {
    var arrFolder = jQuery.grep(this.folders, function(folder,idx) {
        return folder.id == pFolderId;
    });
    if(arrFolder.length > 0) {
        this.manageFoldersPopup.hide();

        var folder = arrFolder[0];
        this.editFolderPopup = new EditFolderPopup(folder);
        this.editFolderPopup.show();
    }
}

this.deleteFolder = function(pFolderId) {
    var safe = confirm('Are you sure ?');
    if(safe) {
        for(var i=0; i<this.folders.length; i++) {
            if(pFolderId == this.folders[i].id) {
                this.folders.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }

        this.renderFolders();
        this.manageFoldersPopup.hide();
        this.manageFolders();
    }
}

this.manageFolders = function() {
    this.manageFoldersPopup = new ManageFoldersPopup(this);
    this.manageFoldersPopup.show();
}

this.renderFolders = function() {
    var mainFoldersDiv = jQuery('#'+this.mainFoldersDivId);
    mainFoldersDiv.empty();

    var fLength = this.folders.length;
    jQuery(this.folders).each(function(index, folder) {
        var folderDivClass = 'inner-folder';
        if(index == 0) folderDivClass = 'first-folder';
        else if(index == fLength-1) folderDivClass = 'bottom-folder';
        var folderDiv = '<div id="'+'tfolder-'+folder.id+'" class="'+folderDivClass+'">';
        folderDiv += folder.getHtmlDiv();
        folderDiv += '</div>';

        mainFoldersDiv.append(folderDiv);
        var titleLink = jQuery('#tfolder-'+folder.id+' .folder-title a');
        titleLink.click(function() {
            folder.onClick();
        });     
    });
}

// Constructor
this.folders.push(new Folder('1','clock.png', 'Travel Diary', 'folder_blue.png'));
this.folders.push(new Folder('2','tag_blue.png', 'Secret Diary', 'folder_brown.png'));
this.folders.push(new Folder('3','post_note.png', 'My Ideas', 'folder_yellow.png'));
this.folders.push(new Folder('4','lock.png', 'Shopping Dubai Mall', 'folder_mov.png'));
this.folders.push(new Folder('5','report.png', 'To-Do List', 'folder_orange.png'));

this.renderFolders();
 } 

  function Folder(pId, pIcon, pTitle, pBgImage) {
    this.id = pId;
    this.icon = pIcon;
    this.title = pTitle;
    this.bgImage = pBgImage;
    this.items = new Array();

    this.getHtmlDiv = function() {
    var result = '<div style="background-image: url(\'<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/'+this.bgImage+'\');" class="folder-image">';
    result += '<span class="folder-icon"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/icons/'+this.icon+'" width="40" height="40" /></span>';
    result += '<span class="folder-title"><a href="#">'+this.title+'</a></span>';
    result += '<span class="folder-item-number">'+this.items.length+'</span>';
    result += '</div>';
    return result;
}

this.onClick = function() {
    var popup = new OpenFolderPopup(this);
    popup.show();
}
 }

 function Note(pId, pTitle, pContent, pDueDate, pFolder) {
    this.id = pId;
    this.title = pTitle;
    this.content = pContent;
    this.dueDate = pDueDate;
    this.folder = pFolder;
}

 function OpenFolderPopup(pFolder) {
       this.folder = pFolder;
       this.jqmdialog = jQuery('#tw-show-folder');

       jQuery('#tw-show-folder .open-folder-header').css('background-image','url("<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/'+this.folder.bgImage+'")');
       jQuery('#tw-show-folder .open-folder-header .open-folder-icon img').attr('src','<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/icons/'+this.folder.icon);
       jQuery('#tw-show-folder .open-folder-title').html(this.folder.title);

       this.jqmdialog.jqm({ modal: false });

       this.show = function() {
      this.jqmdialog.jqmShow();
}
}

  function AddFolderPopup() {
     this.jqmdialog = jQuery('#tw-add-folder');
     this.jqmdialog.css('height','150px');
     this.jqmdialog.css('top','15%');
     this.jqmdialog.jqm({ modal: false });

try {
    jQuery('#tw-add-folder .add-folder-update-icon').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#tw-add-folder .add-folder-save-icon').css('display','block');

    jQuery('#input-folder-title').val('');
    jQuery('#select-folder-icon').val('accept.png');
    jQuery('#select-folder-bgimage').val('folder_blue.png');
    jQuery("#select-folder-icon, #select-folder-bgimage").msDropDown();
} catch(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

this.show = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmShow();
}

this.hide = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmHide();
}
 }

   function ManageFoldersPopup(pTodoObj) {
      this.jqmdialog = jQuery('#tw-manage-folders');
      this.jqmdialog.css('width','450px');
      this.jqmdialog.css('height','400px');
      this.jqmdialog.css('margin-left','-200px');
      this.jqmdialog.css('top','10%');
      this.jqmdialog.jqm({ modal: false });

          var folderTable = jQuery('#table-manage-folders');
      folderTable.empty();
      jQuery(pTodoObj.folders).each(function(index, folder) {
      var result = '<tr id="'+'tfolder-'+folder.id+'">';

       result += '<td>';
       result += '<div style="background-image: url(\'<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/'+folder.bgImage+'\');" class="folder-image">';
       result += '<span class="folder-icon"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/icons/'+folder.icon+'" width="40" height="40" /></span>';
       result += '<span class="folder-title">'+folder.title+'</span>';
       result += '<span class="folder-item-number">'+folder.items.length+'</span>';
       result += '</td>';

       result += '<td>';
       result += '<a class="edit_folder" href="#"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/icons/process.png" width="40px"/></a>';
       result += '</td>';

       result += '<td>';
       result += '<a class="delete_folder" href="#"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/icons/delete.png" width="40px"/></a>';
       result += '</td>';

       result += '</tr>';

        folderTable.append(result);

       jQuery('#table-manage-folders #tfolder-'+folder.id+' .edit_folder').click(function() {
        pTodoObj.editFolder(folder.id);
    });

       jQuery('#table-manage-folders #tfolder-'+folder.id+' .delete_folder').click(function() {
        pTodoObj.deleteFolder(folder.id);
    });     
});

this.show = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmShow();
}

this.hide = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmHide();
}
  }


   function EditFolderPopup(pFolder) {
     this.jqmdialog = jQuery('#tw-add-folder');
     this.jqmdialog.css('height','150px');
     this.jqmdialog.css('top','15%');
     this.jqmdialog.jqm({ modal: false });

    try {
    jQuery('#tw-add-folder .add-folder-update-icon').css('display','block');
    jQuery('#tw-add-folder .add-folder-save-icon').css('display','none');

    jQuery('#input-folder-id').val(pFolder.id);
    jQuery('#input-folder-title').val(pFolder.title);
    jQuery('#select-folder-icon').val(pFolder.icon);
    jQuery('#select-folder-bgimage').val(pFolder.bgImage);
    jQuery("#select-folder-icon, #select-folder-bgimage").msDropDown();
        } catch(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

this.show = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmShow();
}

this.hide = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmHide();
}
 }

   function QuickNotesPopup() {
     this.jqmdialog = jQuery('#tw-quicknotes-popup');
     this.jqmdialog.css('width','445px');
     this.jqmdialog.css('height','300px');
     this.jqmdialog.css('margin-left','-220px');
     this.jqmdialog.jqm({ modal: false });

    jQuery('#quicknotes').tabify();

    this.show = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmShow();
 }

this.hide = function() {
    this.jqmdialog.jqmHide();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do a call using [JQuery Ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to another JSP/servlet back in the server, passing the info that you want to pass as a parameter.

As a matter of security, make the sure that the JSP returns an answer with an error code to know if the transfer was ok.

Comment: Yeah but don't i need to serialize the data using json? the thing is that i want to pass the objects called folder and folderpopup.